# How can I implement call recording in a Flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, call-recording

I'm currently working on a Flutter app that requires call recording functionality. However, I've encountered a challenge in finding suitable plugins or resources for call recording within the Flutter framework. Some opinions I've come across suggest that implementing call recording might not be feasible with Flutter.

I'm seeking guidance on how to approach call recording in a Flutter app. Are there any existing plugins or libraries that can assist with this functionality, or is there a method to implement it without relying on third-party plugins? If it's not possible within the Flutter ecosystem, what alternative approaches or workarounds can I explore?

I'm open to receiving any suggestions, code examples, or links to documentation that can help me get started with call recording in my Flutter app. Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Implementing call recording isn't possible in any language on iOS.  You could implement a VoIP solution and record the call at your server, but you cannot record a cellular call.